# Php array_rand() printing variable name

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have an array that is filled with different sayings and am trying to output a random one of the sayings. My program prints out the random saying, but sometimes it prints out the variable name that is assigned to the saying instead of the actual saying and I am not sure why.

```
$foo=Array('saying1', 'saying2', 'saying3');
$foo['saying1'] = "Hello.";
$foo['saying2'] = "World.";
$foo['saying3'] = "Goodbye.";

echo $foo[array_rand($foo)];
```

So for example it will print World as it should, but other times it will print saying2. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the values at the start. Change the first line to just:

```
$foo = array();
```

What you did was put values 'saying1' and such in the array. You don't want those values in there. You can also drop the index values with:

```
$foo[] = 'Hello.';
$foo[] = 'World.';
```

That simplifies your work.

Answer (score 0):

You declared your array in the wrong way on the first line.
If you want to use your array as an associative Array:

```
$foo=Array('saying1' => array (), 'saying2' => array(), 'saying3' => array());
```

Or you can go for the not associative style given by Kainaw.

Edit: Calling this on the not associative array:

```
echo("<pre>"); print_r($foo); echo("</pre>");
```

Has as output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => saying1
    [1] => saying2
    [2] => saying3
    [saying1] => Hello.
    [saying2] => World.
    [saying3] => Goodbye.
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on what @Answers_Seeker has said, to get your code to work the way you expect it, you'd have to re-declare and initialise your array using one of the methods below:

```
$foo=array('saying1'=>'Hello.', 'saying2'=>'World.', 'saying3'=>'Goodbye.');
```

OR this:

```
$foo=array();
$foo['saying1'] = "Hello.";
$foo['saying2'] = "World.";
$foo['saying3'] = "Goodbye.";
```

Then, to print the contents randomly:

```
echo $foo[array_rand($foo)];
```